# Find and sum all numbers in a cell

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

I need to sum numbers that appear in a string which format is a bit lax.
String can contain numbers (2 or 3 digits long, integers) that can be separated by <kbd>space</kbd>,`,` or letters.

Example data:

| Days | Names | Sum |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Adam100 | 100 |
| 2 | Michał200 Monika300 | 500 |
| 3 | Daniel 200, Rafał100 | 300 |
| 4 | Anna200,Marek 300, J. Nowak 100 | 600 |
| 5 |  | 0 |
| Sum |  | 1500 |

For *Libre Office* I was able to come up with this solution:
`=SUM(VALUE(IFNA(REGEX(B1;"[0-9]+";;ROW(A1:A24));0)))`

and for *Google Spreadsheets*:
`=SUM(SPLIT(IF(A2="";"0"; A2);" "))`

but I can't figure it out for Excel.

Comment: [Excel formula to SUM all numbers in a cell with text - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68547153/excel-formula-to-sum-all-numbers-in-a-cell-with-text)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One option:

```
=IF(A2="","",SUM(0+TEXTSPLIT(A2,TEXTSPLIT(A2,SEQUENCE(10,,0),,1),,1)))
```

Comment: Some explanation of the formula will improve the answer.

Answer (score -1):

If you are working with higher version of Excel like, XL-2021 or 2022 or office 365 then you may try this,

```
=SUM(FILTERXML("<root><data>"&SUBSTITUTE(A1," ","</data><data>")&"</data></root>","//data[number(.) = number(.)]"))
```

**:Edited:**

*This formula considers all possible delimiters like I've used ,,, check the screen shot.*

[image]

```
=SUM(FILTERXML("<t><s>"&SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(M1,";",","),".",",")," ","</s><s>"),",","</s><s>")&"</s></t>","//s[number(.)=.]"))
```

- Adjust cell references as needed.

Comment: Your formula will not work on the data as presented since there are other possible delimiters than the `<space>`

Comment: Your screenshot does **not** replicate the OP's sample data. Try your formula on `Michał200 Monika300`. Note that the number is delimited by the transition between non-digit and digit. Your formula returns `#Value!`

Comment: @RonRosenfeld ,,, is a valid point ,,, but if U examine the OP's sample data has no consistency like in some cells <Space> has been used before numbers but not in other cells,,, since still the OP is no where in the scene so difficult to decide whether OP has missed the <Spaces> or are exactly like that  !!  And  OP has mentioned in the post "**that can be separated by space,, or letters.**"

Comment: The solution by @JosWoolley does provide a solution to the OP's example as posted.

Comment: @RonRosenfeld ,,, yes I've tested it,,,,, also ,,, one problem may have many possible solution,,,, !!